# Xpath get values where a specific text presents

Tags: html, dom, xpath

With xPath I am trying to get the following values:

**html:**

```
<ul class="listVideoAttributes alpha only">
    <li class="alpha only">
        <span>Categories:</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="psi alpha">
                <a href="#">Cinema</a>
            </li>
            <li class="omega">
                <a href="#">HD</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Categories are not always named as categories, sometimes they call it `Tags`.

I would like the following xPath to locate Categories and get the category values
like Cinema and HD.

For now, I'm using:

```
//ul[@class="listVideoAttributes"][contains(., 'Categories:')]
```

and it returns values but also the text 'categories:'.

I would like to do something like:

```
//ul[@class="listVideoAttributes"][contains(., 'Categories:')]/ul
```

But it seems not to work.

Comment: what do you mean by *Categories are not always named as categories, sometimes they call it Tags.* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expresion did not work, because the inner `<ul/>` is not direct child of the outer `<ul/>`. Use the descendant-or-self axis step `//ul` instead of the child axis step `/ul` at the end of your expression. If you're sure the markup will not change, better only use child axis steps: `/li/ul/li/a`.

Another problem is that the `@class` attribute does not equal `listVideoAttributes`, but only contain it. You should never compare HTML-class-attributes with equals, always use contains.

---

Anyway, I'd be as specific as possible while searching for the "headline", otherwise you could find false positives when the content of any "listVideoAttributes"-list contains one "Categories" or "Tags":

```
//ul[contains(@class, 'listVideoAttributes')]/li[contains(span, 'Categories') or contains(span, 'Tags')]//a
```

You might want to add a `/text()` if you cannot read the string value from the programming language you're using which would usually be preferred (eg., when a link contains bold text like `<a href="..."><strong>foo</strong><a>`; `text()` wouldn't return the string value in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below **Xpath**

```
//ul[contains(@class,'listVideoAttributes') and contains(.//span,'Categories')]//a/text()
```

***output:***

```
Cinema
HD
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with

```
//ul[@class="listVideoAttributes"][contains(., 'Categories:')]/ul
```

first the outer `ul` class is not *equal to* "listVideoAttributes", it only *contains* that as a substring, and secondly the inner `ul` is not a direct child of the outer one, it's a grandchild.  How about

```
//ul[contains(@class, 'listVideoAttributes')][contains(., 'Categories')]/li/ul/li/a
```